# Boolean expression for string to have at least one of multiple substrings

Tags: java

I need to check a `String` field to see if it contains at least one of 2 different substrings. It should either contain "ABC" or "XYZ". If not, I am setting an error. My current code:

```
if(userTitle!=null && !userTitle.contains("ABC")){//error}
```

How do I expand this to check if it contains "ABC" or "XYZ"?

Comment: Show your code. Also, I think you could do `if (theString.contains("ABC") || theString.contains("XYZ")) { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(userTitle != null && !(userTitle.contains("ABC") || userTitle.contains("XYZ"))
```

This is the condition that you want.

Best way to write such things is just to write it as you would say in natural language: "if it does **not** contain ( ABC **or** XYZ ) then.."

The resulting expression can than be simplified by using De Morgan's laws. Search for this and you will surely find an easy explanation of them somewhere.

Comment: I hope he understands boolean logic `>.<`

Comment: Thanks. Will try this code. I think that would work. Will confirm.